# Include a screenshot of the story as it appears on a user’s timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, screenshot

I have submited my Facebook app recently and I got the feedback from facebook that my app didn't include the screénhot of the sory as it appears on a user's timeline. But the problem here is I cannot find where to submit the screenshot. I have already include all of the screenshots in App Details section. Please tell me where to put the screenshot which is required by Facebook?
Here is the screenshot of Facebook's feedback:
http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8022/capturego.png
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You include the screenshots when you are submitting the action.

[image: Action submit with screenshot]

Comment: I've already include screenshot at that section, but Facebook still report that I didn't include the screenshots. That's why I stucked at this problem.

Comment: Additional info: My application is an iOS app, and I included the screenshots which describe the steps to share a link to facebook. This is the screénhot: http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/6853/capture1ul.png Please help me.

Comment: Include your screenshots in your question above @user2396783

Comment: I dont get it, I have included all the necessary screenshots. And still get the report from Facebook.